# after install jetstream login and registration not working as usual

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

I created fresh laravel project and install jetstream but login page , registration page view and their functions not worikng as usual. registraion is working but logout is not working well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

go to (app.blade.php, guest.blade.php) and remove @vite like this

> @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js']) => Remove this
> and add the following

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Comment: Yes this is for UI thanks